# Can't get the right DateTime (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a column that has a datetime data types.

Whenever I update the column like this.

```
new_date = "2014-12-13 03:43:30".to_datetime 
Model.first.update_column(:my_datetime, new_date) => true
```

But when I do quest like this.

```
Model.first.my_datetime  => "Sat, 13 Dec 2014 11:43:30 HKT +08:00"
```

It supposed to output `03:43:30`

Please help thanks!

Comment: check this to get your own kinda format http://www.dzone.com/snippets/date-time-format-ruby

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime):

```
new_date.strftime("%T")
#=> "03:43:30"
```

or applying it on activerecord response:

```
new_date = "2014-12-13 03:43:30".to_datetime
Model.first.update_column(:my_datetime, new_date) 
#=> true
Model.first.my_datetime.strftime("%T")
#=> "03:43:30"
```

Here `%T` is for `Local time (extended)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Zone 
Use `Time.zone.now`